# Capistrano - with ":keep_releases" the deployment doesn't pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, capistrano

I wanted to keep on the server only recent 5 releases, so I added following to the `deploy/production.rb` file:

```
set :keep_releases, 5
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
```

But the problem is that when I run `cap production deploy`, the deployment runs well until this point:

```
 ** transaction: commit
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update'
  * 2015-01-20 14:12:47 executing `deploy:cleanup'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ls -1dt /home/deployer/apps/appname/releases/* | tail -n +6 | sudo -p 'sudo password: ' xargs rm -rf"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
 ** [out :: IP]
```

and here the deployment stuck - I've been waiting for an hour, maybe something over an hour, but nothing changed - the deployment hasn't finished.

Do I miss something? Without those two lines in config the deployment takes just like a minute.

What's wrong here? I am using Rails 4 and Capistrano 2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to specify :keep_releases in deploy.rb, instead of production.rb

And default number of releases is 5.

My deploy.rb

```
# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5
```